# How to install Umbraco extension on Web hosting server using panel?

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, add-on

i've successfully created CMS in Umbraco 4.11 and hosted it on web hosting server. Web hosting (arvixe) panel has Web app gallery which had Umbraco 4.9. So i needed to request to install 4.11 version.

Now after they installed it, im again stucked as there is no way of installing uComponents to Umbraco. i installed uComponenets on my local server using webMatrix but on Web hosting panel it is totally different story.

Has any one experience the same problem while making Umbraco App live on web hosting server?

if YES then please help me out with the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login and go to the developer area where you will find a Packages section through which you can install ucomponents.